# In c++ what does if(a=b) mean? versus if(a==b)

Tags: c++

Probably been answered, but could not find it.

In c++ what does

```
if(a=b)
```

mean? 
versus

```
if(a==b)
```

I just spent two hours debugging to find that

```
if(a=b)
```

compiles as

```
a=b
```

Why does compiler not flag

```
if(a=b)
```

as an error?

Comment: It's a valid thing to do, just weird and usually not what people want. "Usually not what people want" isn't a compile-time error.

Comment: Usually `a=b` assigns the value of `b` to `a` and returns a reference to `a`. You can override it.

Comment: Your assumptions are not quite right. You are stumbling over a common beginner problem. In the if statement you make an assignment, so the value of b gets assigned to a. Then the value of a gets evaluated, which is true if a is unequal to 0. It is valid c/c++ syntax so there is no error, but your compiler should gave you a warning

Comment: compilers can emit a warning for using assignments in conditions, read your compiler manual and cranck up warning levels

Comment: Modern compilers give you a warning (gcc needs -Wall for that, clang does it out of the box): https://godbolt.org/z/SLCzZo

Comment: This should be explained in every C++ book. What does your book say about this, and is there anything in its explanation that you don't understand? Stackoverflow is not really a replacement for a formal C++ textbook. It is not an error because this is valid C++ code. Just because valid C++ code does something other than what you want it to do doesn't make it an error.

Comment: Assignment in `if` condition does not need to be a programming mistake. Consider a simple example such as `if (errcode = some_c_function()) { /* process error */ }`. Compiler warning in such cases would be annoying.

Comment: ***I just spent two hours debugging to find that*** You probably did not step through your code 1 line at a time. Looking at the variables at each step. Although with that said if you have a code base like mine where an average program is greater than 50 thousand lines of code (probably worked on over a period of several years) and this bug is in code that is rarely executed and you wrote the code several years ago 2 hours may not even find such a bug...

Answer (score 8):

> In c++ what does if(a=b) mean?

`a=b` is an assignment expression. If the type of `a` is primitive, or if the assignment operator is generated by the compiler, then the effect of such assignment is that the value of `a` is modified to match `b`. Result of the assignment will be lvalue referring to `a`.

If the operator is user defined, then it can technically have any behaviour, but it is conventional to conform to the expectations by doing similar modification and return of the left operand.

The returned value is converted to `bool` which affects whether the following statement is executed.

> versus
>
> ```
> if(a==b)
> ```

`a==b` is an equality comparison expression. Nothing is assigned. If the types are primitive, or if the comparison operator is generated by the compiler, then the result will be true when the operands are equal and otherwise false.

If the operator is user defined, then it can technically have any behaviour, but it is conventional to conform to the expectations by doing similar equality comparison.

> Why does compiler not flag
>
> ```
> if(a=b)
> ```
>
> as an error?

Because it is a well-formed expression (fragment) as long as `a` is assignable with `b`.

`if(a=b)` is a conventional pattern to express the operation of setting value of a variable, and having conditional behaviour depending on the new value.

Some compilers do optionally "flag" it with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you would assign value `int a = 1` and you make an if statement

```cpp
if (a = 2)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

It still works, even though they are two different values, they will do the `std::cout`

However if you use a double equals sign `==` it will not.

The reason for this is if you use the standard double equals sign `==` you are asking the code if `a` is equivalent to 2, if it is 2. Obviously it's not, so it doesn't `std::cout`. But if you use an equals sign, you are changing the value `a` to 2, so it continues with the if statement.

And, to prove this, try taking away the `int a = 1` from before the if statement and add an `int` before a in the if statement, it works.

Comment: There's also the easier proof, try reversing it: `if (0 = a)`. The compiler will complain.